# How to check for blank cell using getcell in exceljs

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I am writing a code where i am checking the contents of an excel file using exceljs. I have to check if a cell is empty but I am unable to do that. I have tried the following things:

```
if(!worksheet.getCell(`L${colNumber}`).value)
if(worksheet.getCell(`L${colNumber}`).value === '')
if(worksheet.getCell(`L${colNumber}`).value == null)
if(worksheet.getCell(`L${colNumber}`).value === undefined)
if(worksheet.getCell(`L${colNumber}`).value.length === 0) //logging it gave the length as 1
if(!!worksheet.getCell(`L${colNumber}`).value)
```

Comment: what is the output if you log ```worksheet.getCell(`L${colNumber}`).value``` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on non empty columns cells by using

```
const dobCol = worksheet.getColumn(3);

// iterate over all current cells in this column excluding empty cells

dobCol.eachCell({ includeEmpty: false }, function(cell, rowNumber) {
   ...
});
```

As described in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#columns-)

Comment: the question is asking how to check whether a cell is empty, not how to iterate non-empty cells